# Facebook "like" button does not display

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I have been trying to put a facebook "like" button in one of my webpages. To do that, In the process of doing this, I copied an example at "[Like Button Configurator](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button)" by facebook, but no "like" button shows up. I ran it against the facebook debugger, but found no errors (except one complaint about the size of "og:image" picture). I also searched/reviewed related posts/answers in this forum. Any advice on how did I do it wrong will be greatly appreciated.

My test page is [here](http://liquibil.com/fb-like.html). You're welcome to examine the source by "view source" on the test page.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this code

*After body:*

```html
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  (function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s);
    js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/ru_RU/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.4";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
<div class="fb-like" data-href="https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/" data-layout="button_count" data-action="like" data-show-faces="true" data-share="false"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I examine the attach code segment and believe it is the same as I used, except that "js.src=..." which yours ends with "version=v2.4", and mine does not, and yours is Russian and mine is "English". Is this the same snippet from facebook's "Like Button Configurator"?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I need to add "&appId=xxxxxxxxx" at the end of the following line:
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/ru_RU/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.4"; to make it

js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/ru_RU/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.4&appId=xxxxxxx"

where xxxxx is a valid Facebook AppId. It works now.